# Why is my AWS CloudWatch alarm not being triggered?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, cloudwatch-alarms

I'm trying to setup AWS to send notifications to a slack channel when a CloudWatch alarm goes off. I'm following along in this guide:

https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/generate-slack-notifications-for-aws-cloudwatch-alarms-e46b68540133

I think I did everything properly but I'm not getting my slack notifications. I'm not sure where in the process it's failing but I suspect the alarm is not being triggered.

Here are the details:

CloudWatch logs shows my error is being logged:

[image]

Here is my filter metric:

[image]

Here is how I define the pattern on which I want to filter:

[image]

Here is the state of the alarm:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

The alarm seems to be OK. I gave it 5 minutes after logging the error. Does this mean the alarm is not being triggered?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

Here are some updated screen shots to address Marcin's point about the time discrepancy (note that the CloudWatch logs are in local time and the Alarm graph is in UTC--a 6 hour difference):

[image]

[image]

I'm not exactly sure how to interpret the graph. It says OK in the top right corner but the horizontal red line at 1 seems to indicate that it's in an alarm state.

Comment: It might be related to the fact that the alarm is checking the **AVERAGE** value over a 5-minute period. Can you change it to **SUM** instead?

Comment: Your logs show that error messages were at after 12. Your alarm starts at 15.  So there is some discrepancy hear.

Comment: I changed it to SUM, still not triggering

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that there must be something wrong between your pattern filter and the alarm trigger since you clearly have the message in your log stream and the alarm condition has been met.

I'm more used to seeing filter patterns in JSON, but going over the documentation at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/FilterAndPatternSyntax.html there's a line that says:

> Metric filter terms that include characters other than alphanumeric or underscore must be placed inside double quotes ("").

And I'm thinking that your message pattern has a dash and it's neither alphanumeric nor an underscore on it so maybe *that*'s the part that's being interpreted differently than expected.

Comment: Thanks Oscar, I'll give that a try after I'm done dealing with AWS support. They investigated the issue and replied saying the alarm IS triggering as the problem appears to be with my lambda function for sending the notification to Slack. If it turns out they're wrong, I'll give your suggestion a try.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that CloudWatch Filter's need to be quoted if they have characters other than alphanumerics and underscores.

Since your pattern has dashes in it, you will need to put your filter pattern in double quotes.  Without quotes, CloudWatch may interpret dashes as minus signs used to exclude terms.

`"LOGIN-SIGNUP-ERROR"`

Also, as it was already discussed in the comments, you should change the statistic to `SUM` instead of `AVERAGE` assuming you want to be alerted each time this error occurs.

References:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/FilterAndPatternSyntax.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply JD; see my comment to Oscar.